# Cannot push to github due to SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL

Tags: git, git-push

I can add and commit, but I cannot push to any repo. The error message goes like this:
fatal: unable to access '[my github repo]': LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to github.com:443

I re-installed git and got the same error. I tried to change repo, and even others' public repo, and got the same error, except the last three digits were a bit different - 403.

The problem happens to both Mac and Windows. I'm using Astrill VPN, but the problem exists even when I turn it off.

-- Update: -- 
I used git config --global --unset http.proxy and it worked, but after I pushed to this repo, I need to do it again to push to my friend's repo. So I think the question is, how to make git not set a proxy automatically after each push.

Comment: Is there any antivirus installed in your machine ??

Comment: Not that I can think of. Any way to check?

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have:

- a `~/.curlrc`
- a `no_proxy` environment variable defined. I have seen that `SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL` in cases where the proxy was defined but should not have been used.

> I think the question is, how to make git not set a proxy automatically after each push.

Set `no_proxy` to `github.com`:

```
export no_proxy=github.com
```

Even if a proxy is defined, it won't apply to push to GitHub because of the `no_proxy` environment variable.

Comment: I don't have ~/.curlrc;

Comment: @JackBoyuanChen I have edited the answer to address your question about proxy.

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to use a proxy then set *https_proxy* to the *ip address* and *port* of your choice like so: `export https_proxy=ip_address:port`